# Sharepoint as a CMS

Tags: sharepoint

I do not know anything about Sharepoint, and my company is rolling it out in a few departments.
I am familiar with the workings and usage of Oracle (Stellent) CMS (for storing docs with meta-data, searching for docs, etc), and I am asking if I may use Sharepoint in a similar way?
Can I programmatically upload docs to Sharepoint, from a java web application, and do searches and doc retrieval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You are able to do all of that from Java via the MOSS 2k7 Web Services. Here's a quick reference for uploading a  file to a list (the example uses .NET, but you can use Java just as easily).

[David Klein's  Corner: Uploading Files to MOSS 2007 via the Copy.asmx Web Service](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/01/uploading-files-to-moss-2007-via.html)

Comment: Well, not just as easily... but it does have a *fairly* comprehensive SOAP layer.

Comment: I think using SharePoint as a development platform is a bad idea... it's good create sites and document libraries but anything custom is such a nightmare...